# How to get index item that has : "name" - "McLaren" by searching with "mclaren" in Elasticsearch 1.7?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the tokenizer -

```
"tokenizer": {
   "filename" : {
      "pattern" : "[^\\p{L}\\d]+",
      "type" : "pattern"
   }
},
```

Mapping -

```
"name": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "filename_index",
      "include_in_all": true,
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "lower_case_sort": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "naturalsort"
        }
      }
    },
```

Analyzer -

```
"filename_index" : {
         "tokenizer" : "filename",
         "filter" : [
          "word_delimiter", 
          "lowercase",
          "russian_stop", 
          "russian_keywords", 
          "russian_stemmer",
          "czech_stop",
          "czech_keywords",
          "czech_stemmer"
        ]
      },
```

I would like to get index item by searching - mclaren, but the name indexed is McLaren.
I would like to stick to query_string cause a lot of other functionality is based on that. Here is the query with what I cant get the expected result -

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "query_string" : {
                "query" : "mclaren",
                "default_operator" : "AND",
                "analyze_wildcard" : true,
            }
        }
    }
},
"size" :50,
"from" : 0,
"sort": {}
}
```

How I could accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: Hello could you tell us if you have a value for the setting index.query.default_field ?

Comment: If you are talking about mapping.json file then no. I dont have such property set.

Comment: no i meant what is the result of this query GET<your-index-name>/_settings/index.query.default_field* ??

Comment: It is empty object.

Comment: And if I add it to the "settings" then I get this - 
{
    "files2": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "query": {
                    "default_field": "name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But the query still does not return what I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ! The problem is certainly around the `word_delimiter` token filter.
By default it :

> Split tokens at letter case transitions. For example: PowerShot →
> Power, Shot

Cf [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html#analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter)

So macLaren generate two tokens -> [mac, Laren] when maclaren only generate one token ['maclaren'].

analyze example :

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "pattern": """[^\p{L}\d]+""",
    "type": "pattern"
  },
  "filter": [
    "word_delimiter"
  ],
  "text": ["macLaren", "maclaren"]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "mac",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "Laren",
      "start_offset" : 3,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "maclaren",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 17,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 102
    }
  ]
}
```

So I think one option is to configure your word_delimiter with the option `split_on_case_change` to false (see [parameters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html#word-delimiter-tokenfilter-configure-parms) doc)

**Ps: remeber to remove the settings you previously added (cf comments), since with this setting, your query string query will only target the `name` field that does not exists.**

Comment: Wonderful! It is working by adding "split_on_case_change" : false to the filter. Thank you!